# Routing query params without slash before it in react-location

Tags: reactjs, react-location

Previously, I was using react-router-dom. With react-router-dom, I could define a route with query params like this:

```
<Route path="/p:productId" element={<Products />} /> // localhost:3000/p1 will match this route
```

But it seems like react-location doesn't work in the same way. The only way that I found is by defining the query params as a child of another route, but this leads to a slash before the actual letter 'p'.

The following example comes from the official documentation, but I'll rewrite it to match our own example.

```
const routes = [
 {
  path: 'p',
  children: [
    {
     path: ':productId', // matches /p/:productId . localhost:3000/p/1 will match this route.
    },
  ],
 },
]
```

Is it possible to make it like the first example, which comes from react-router-dom?
Regardless of the answer, is it a bad practice to do it like the first example?